# Apply different filters on multiple index search

Tags: symfony, foselasticabundle

I'm using FOSElasticaBundle with Symfony 3. I want to search on different index in ES6.

I have 2 entities Dogs, Cats with a field name "owner" (entity User). Dogs and Cats have a field "name" (string), I want to search every Dogs and only Cats that have it owner set at userId.

Example:

- User: #1 Bob
- User: #2 Charle
- Cat: #1 Ruf, owner #1
- Cat: #2 Pat, owner #2
- Dog: #1 Ruf
- Dog: #2 Pat

If I'm Bob, and I write "Ruf". I want as result Cat#1, Dog#1 but if i write "Pat", I want as result Dog#2.

elastica.yml

```
fos_elastica:
   clients:
       default:
           host: %elastic_host%
           port: %elastic_port%
   indexes:
       dog:
           finder: ~
           client: default
           types:
               dog:
                   indexable_callback: 'getEnabled'
                   properties:
                       id:
                          type: integer
                       name: ~
                   persistence:
                       driver: orm
                       model: AppBundle\Entity\Dog
                       finder: ~
                       elastica_to_model_transformer:
                          ignore_missing: true

       cat:
            finder: ~
            client: default
            types:
                cat:
                    indexable_callback: 'getEnabled'
                    properties:
                        name: ~
                        owner:
                          type: "object"
                          properties:
                              id: integer
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\Cat
                        finder: ~
                        elastica_to_model_transformer:
                          ignore_missing: true
```

I'm searching in ES with the method:

```
public function search(User $user, $query)
{
    $search = $this->indexManager->getIndex('dog')->createSearch();
    $search->addIndex('cat');

    $search->addType('dog');
    $search->addType('cat');

    $resultSet = $search->search($query);

    return $this->formatResult($resultSet);
}
```

How can i do my search ? Should i use Filter on Cat ? Could i use one repository per indexes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can search using multiple indexes using ruflin/elastica.
It would be something like:

```
$search = new Elastica\Search($client);
$search->addIndex('dog')->addIndex('cat');
try {
    $searchResponse = $search->search($q);

    return $searchResponse->getResults();
} catch (ResponseException $exception) {
    return [];
}
```

I'm sorry, but I do not know how to do this with FOSElasticaBundle.

Answer (score 0):

finder should search by all indexes:
`@fos_elastica.finder.app`

result query look like:

```
    $boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

    /*****************DOG PART**********************/
    $dogBoolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

    $dogNameMatchQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Term();
    $dogNameMatchQuery->setTerm('name', $query);

    $dogTypeFilter = new \Elastica\Query\Type();
    $dogTypeFilter->setType('dog');

    $dogBoolQuery->addMust($dogNameMatchQuery);
    $dogBoolQuery->addFilter($dogTypeFilter);
    /***************************************/


    /*****************CAT PART**********************/
    $catBoolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

    $catTypeFilter = new \Elastica\Query\Type();
    $catTypeFilter->setType('cat');

    $ownerNameTermQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Term();
    $ownerNameTermQuery->setTerm('id', $user->getId());

    $ownerQuery = new \Elastica\Query\HasParent($ownerNameTermQuery, 'owner');

    $catBoolQuery->addFilter($catTypeFilter);
    $catBoolQuery->addFilter($ownerQuery);
    /***************************************/


    $boolQuery->addShould($dogBoolQuery);
    $boolQuery->addShould($catBoolQuery);

    $searchQuery = new \Elastica\Query();
    $searchQuery->setQuery($boolQuery);

    $results = $this->finder->find($searchQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do two separate searches, one for each index. If you need a single query for pagination purposes, then I would use the Elasticsearch api directly, as I'm not sure if the FosElasticaBundle supports this kind of searches.
You can find how to do multiple indices search in the [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) using Curl calls to the ES api.